# How to redirect when the focus in input is false in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input, autofocus

i have a some view in vue, when open a search view it's automatic focus on input, then when it not focusing again the view must redirect back

I have searched for this problem or solution and do my best but i'ts not work
i use Vue JS 2
here my code :

```html
<input v-focus="focused" @focus="focused = true" @blur="focused = false" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="search">
```

```
import { focus } from 'vue-focus'

export default {
  directives: { focus: focus },
  data () {
    return {
      focused: true
    }
  }
}
```

i use [vue-focus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-focus) package, if you suggest me a native i'ts oke

i would like if the input not focusing again i'ts automatic go back to another link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `@blur="focused = false"`, you can actually do `@blur="goBack"`, where `goBack` is a local method which changes the route according to what you want.

If you're using `vue router`, something like `this.$router.go(-1)` works.

Comment: it's works ! thanks, but now i have a error, inside the view with the input, have a link like history search, if i click the history link it's make to goback to previous link not to target link, can you fix that?

Comment: u can both use `this.$router.replace` in your middle link or use `this.$router.push(TARGET_ROUTE)` instead of `this.$router.go(-1)`